# Android studio problems with onclick

Tags: javascript, android-studio

So..I want that on every 100 clicks or 1000 points (same thing) to show that toast.. I have this code

```
public void DestroyTheCube(View v) {
        points = points + 10;
        castig.setText("Points: " + points);
        if (points == 100  ) {
            Toast.makeText(Activ1.this,"Merge",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

But it's dosen't work, because if I have more than 100 points the toast will never show again.. "DestroyTheCube" it's a onclick from a ImageButton. Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: You say you want the toast every 1000 points, but the code appears to be looking for every 100 points?

Comment: The principal idea was the same. I know what I write there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `points % 1000 == 0`. The `%` is the *modulo* operator and returns the remainder of `a / b`. Checking that the remainder is 0 is the same as checking that `a` is evenly divisible by `b`.